# Android linking jar JRE1.7 NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, sqlite, java, noclassdeffounderror

I have an android 2.1 app and a separate JRE jar library with core methods of the app, compatible with other web apps. The core uses sqlite4java.

When I specify to compile the library with JRE1.6 there is no problem accessing the classes of the jar library from the app, but as the library uses sqlite4java it doesn't work because it needs to be JRE1.7 (Complains with "*Couldn't load sqlite4java-android-armv6l*")

When I specify to the library to compile in JRE1.7, it compiles ok, runs ok the app but when the app tries to access to any class in the library it fails with NoClassDefFoundError. During compiling I get the following error with each class of the library:

```
[2012-05-31 13:00:21 - AndroidApp-0.2] Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing com/androidapp/core/RES.class
...while processing com/tonads/androidapp/RES.class
```

I tried to put in classpath the directory where my library is but no result. Also in manifest included every .jar and .class file that the library uses.
After exhaustive googling, couldn't find any solution. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but as the library uses sqlite4java it doesn't work because it needs to be JRE1.7

First, Android does not support Java 7.

Second, since [that project has an outstanding issue to confirm Java 7 compatibility](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/issues/detail?id=38), I suspect that your theory regarding Java 7 is incorrect.

Comment: Great! then I don't understand one point: When I use the jar (compiled in JRE1.6) with a JRE1.7 java app, sqlite4java works fine, loading sqlite4java-win32-x86.dll. When I try it with the Android app, it complains of "*Couldn't load sqlite4java-android-armv6l*". If I look at the libraries that sqlite4java comes with, there is *libsqlite4java-android-armv7.so* but not *sqlite4java-android-armv6l*. Any idea how to solve?

Comment: @Miguel: Only the developers of the library can answer that. My guess is that you are simply putting it in the wrong place. It would need to go in the correctly-named subdirectory under `libs/`, but the subdirectory name depends on how they built that `.so` using the NDK.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. Asked to the developers but no answer. At the end changed to sqlDroid. It's a pitty that Google reinvented the wheel with SQLite management and they don't provide (documented) standard methods. Regarding second point, sqlite4java is working fine for me with Java 7.